# troubles finding a specific string in a structure

Tags: c, function, strstr

I'm trying to implement the following function but my code is not functional. Any ideas why?

```c
int *colecao_pesquisa_nome(colecao *c, const char *nomep, int *tam);
```

Return an indices array referring to the position of all plants that present the full
scientific name or any of the local names equal to nomep. Returns by reference the
array’s size (`tam`). If it’s unsuccessful, the function should return `NULL`.

```c
int *colecao_pesquisa_nome(colecao *c, const char *nomep, int *tam)
{   if(c==NULL || nomep==NULL)return NULL;
    long i=0,a,z=0,y=0;
    int *indice=NULL;
    
    for (i = 0; i < c->tamanho; i++)
    {
        if (strstr(c->plantas[i]->nome_cientifico, nomep)!= NULL)
        {
            indice=(int*)realloc(indice,sizeof(int)*(z+1));
            indice[z]=i;
             z=z+1;
        }
    
        if(strstr(c->plantas[i]->nome_cientifico, nomep) == NULL){
            for(a=0;a<c->plantas[i]->n_alcunhas;a++){;
               if (strstr(c->plantas[i]->alcunhas[a], nomep) != NULL){
                   indice=(int*)realloc(indice,sizeof(int)*(z+1));
                   indice[z]=i;
                   z=z+1;
                   break;
                }
            }  
        }
    }
    *tam=z;
    return indice;
}
```

Comment: You `break;` after the second `if (...)`, but not after the first -- is that indented?

Comment: `*tam=sizeof(*indice);` -->> `*tam=z;`

Comment: tam should be equal do z but my program is finding the word where she is not so  z is getting higher and higher so i cant use it but  tam = sizeof(indice) is not right too , i only do the break in the second because i only need to find the word once

Comment: Need structure definitions.

Comment: In `if (strstr(c->plantas[i]->nome_cientifico, nomep)!= NULL) ... if(strstr(c->plantas[i]->nome_cientifico, nomep) == NULL)` that second if could just be the word `else`, couldn't it?

Comment: I am not sure but https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc says `reallocates the given area of memory. It must be previously allocated by malloc(), calloc() or realloc()...` And your first `realloc` call reallocates a pointer pointing to void.  I don't think that's allowed.  Maybe when you call realloc you should test for NULL and malloc instead?